# Which url should I use for soap on android?

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, httprequest

I have to use web service on android without using 3.rd party libraries like ksoap. So I must write my own requests. And this point which url should I use for post url?

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url");
```

I have wsdl link like that:

```
http://kavakci.com.tr/kod.merkezi/rotametre.asmx?WSDL  (not working for you, just for me)
```

Soap action:

```
http://kavakci.com.tr/BaglantiDogrula
```

Method:

```
BaglantiDogrula
```

Namespace:

```
http://kavakci.com.tr/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common practice to be able to access the WSDL of  a web service by its endpoint address suffixed with "?WSDL", which means that you should POST your request to:

```
http://kavakci.com.tr/kod.merkezi/rotametre.asmx
```

Comment: So, if I want to call "BaglantiDogrula" method under web service, does url change? How can I call "BaglantiDogrula". Can you give me an example link about calling web servis without using third party libraries?

Comment: @gurcan15: The URL remains the same no matter what web service operation you are calling. You have to build the proper SOAP payload for each method and change the SOAPAction, but the endpoint is the same for all operations exposed by the web service. [See this post for an example of a web service call without third party libraries](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-calling-web-services/).